# Conditional imports / code for Dart packages

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Is there any way to conditionally import libraries / code based on environment flags or target platforms in Dart? I'm trying to switch out between `dart:io`'s ZLibDecoder / ZLibEncoder classes and zlib.js based on the target platform.

There is an article that describes how to [create a unified interface](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/06/create-unified-interfaces-across-dartio.html), but I'm unable to visualize that technique not creating duplicate code and redundant tests to test that duplicate code. `game_loop` [employs this technique](https://github.com/johnmccutchan/game_loop/tree/4385b019f2bb97b7c849a547451acfb30802caa2/lib), but uses separate classes (GameLoopHtml and GameLoopIsolate) that don't seem to share anything.

My code looks a bit like this:

```dart
class Parser {
  Layer parse(String data) {
    List<int> rawBytes = /* ... */;
    /* stuff you don't care about */
    return new Layer(_inflateBytes(rawBytes));
  }
  String _inflateBytes(List<int> bytes) {
    // Uses ZLibEncoder on dartvm, zlib.js in browser
  }
}
```

I'd like to avoid duplicating code by having two separate classes -- ParserHtml and ParserServer -- that implement everything identically except for `_inflateBytes`.

EDIT: concrete example here: https://github.com/radicaled/citadel/blob/master/lib/tilemap/parser.dart. It's a TMX (Tile Map XML) parser.

Comment: If they both implement everything identically, why don't you implement it in an extract class and then have ParserHtml and ParserServer extend that class?

Comment: I intend to have other classes that directly access or instantiate `Parser` and I'm not sure how I can handle that without having them directly reference ParserHtml or ParserServer. Maybe there's some factory pattern I can use for that, though.

Comment: import parserhtml.dart, which defines a class Parser which is a subclass of the real one and has a factory constructor to the html version. Do likewise for the server version. Then the code can be the same except for what it imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use mirrors (reflection) to solve this problem. The pub package *[path](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path)* is using reflection to access `dart:io` on the standalone VM or `dart:html` in the browser.

The source is located [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/path/lib/path.dart). The good thing is, that they use `@MirrorsUsed`, so only the required classes are included for the mirrors api. In my opinion the code is documented very good, it should be easy to adopt the solution for your code.

Start at the getters `_io` and `_html` (stating at line 72), they show that you can load a library without that they are available on your type of the VM. Loading just returns false if the library it isn't available.

```dart
/// If we're running in the server-side Dart VM, this will return a
/// [LibraryMirror] that gives access to the `dart:io` library.
///
/// If `dart:io` is not available, this returns null.
LibraryMirror get _io => currentMirrorSystem().libraries[Uri.parse('dart:io')];

// TODO(nweiz): when issue 6490 or 6943 are fixed, make this work under dart2js.
/// If we're running in Dartium, this will return a [LibraryMirror] that gives
/// access to the `dart:html` library.
///
/// If `dart:html` is not available, this returns null.
LibraryMirror get _html =>
  currentMirrorSystem().libraries[Uri.parse('dart:html')];
```

Later you can use mirrors to invoke methods or getters. See the getter `current` (starting at line 86) for an example implementation.

```dart
/// Gets the path to the current working directory.
///
/// In the browser, this means the current URL. When using dart2js, this
/// currently returns `.` due to technical constraints. In the future, it will
/// return the current URL.
String get current {
  if (_io != null) {
    return _io.classes[#Directory].getField(#current).reflectee.path;
  } else if (_html != null) {
    return _html.getField(#window).reflectee.location.href;
  } else {
    return '.';
  }
}
```

As you see in the comments, this only works in the Dart VM at the moment. After issue [6490](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?can=2&q=6490%20&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=6490) is solved, it should work in Dart2Js, too. This may means that this solution isn't applicable for you at the moment, but would be a solution later.

The issue [6943](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?can=2&q=6943%20&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=6943) could also be helpful, but describes another solution that is not implemented yet.

Comment: This seems like it has the best long-term potential, so I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Conditional imports are possible based on the presence of `dart:html` or `dart:io`, see for example the import statements of [resource_loader.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/resource/blob/master/lib/src/resource_loader.dart) in [package:resource](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/resource).

I'm not yet sure how to do an import conditional on being on the Flutter platform.