# Is it possible to compile code conditional in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to compile my Flutter code for web with a different dependency as for android. There is no dependency which supports both, so I need to find another way.

I found in the web the build.yaml but I dont understand it quite yet. Maybe this is the right option for me and somebody can help me understand it better (Thanks :D).

It should be on compile stage seperated because if I compile for web the android dependencys are blocking the compilation.

```
Skipping compiling pay_balance|lib/main_web_entrypoint.dart with ddc because some of its
transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform:

firebase_core|lib/firebase_core.dart

https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-resolve-skipped-compiling-warnings
```

The endresult should be a Code which has different dependencys for web and android and not compile the other one. So when i develop for web the android dependencys should not be compiled!

Comment: Did you try using conditional imports..! Something similar has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525433/conditional-imports-code-for-dart-packages) if you are thinking in the along the same line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional imports / code for Dart packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525433/conditional-imports-code-for-dart-packages)

Comment: You have to distinguish your source code for `Android`, `iOS` and `Web`, because all of flutter libraries are not fully compatible with all these platforms. Also you should consider that some libraries are meaningless for other platforms (e.g. `sqflite` which is meaningless for `Web`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use conditional imports as mentioned above. I did this recently and this is how:

You'll need a bit of verbose file creation but its not too bad.
`my_service.dart` - used to do the import

`my_service_main.dart` - will be used to stub out the initial import because of the way Dart imports currently work

`my_service_web.dart` - will import Web specific libraries such as `dart:html` and do the web version of what you're trying to implement

`my_service_mobile.dart` - will import iOS/Android libraries such as `dart:io` and do the mobile version

---

1. Create these 4 files
2. Make sure your method is named the same thing in each
3. `throw UnsupportedError` from the "main" version
4. Handle imports

---

Putting it all together

```
// my_service_main.dart

void doTheThing() => throw UnsupportedError('doTheThing Unsupported')

// my_service_web.dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

void doTheThing(){
  // do your thing, use `html`, etc
}

//my_service_mobile.dart
import 'dart:io';

void doTheThing(){
  // do your thing using dart:io
}

// The export file
// my_service.dart

export 'my_service_main.dart'
  if (dart.library.js) 'my_service_web.dart'
  if (dart.library.io) 'my_service_mobile.dart'



// Then in your code you can import
import 'my_service.dart';

void main() {
  doTheThing();
}
```