# flutter compile time conditional

Tags: flutter, web, compilation, preprocessor, isolate

i've added a background isolate and it works fine on macOs and android, but as soon as i `flutter run -d chrome` i.e. compile for web i get a compile time error:

```
[...] Error: Member not found:
'BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized'.
    BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(input.rootIsolateToken);
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which makes sense since that's not supported in web

but how can i omit this when compiling for web, i tried this but it wont work:

```dart
if (!kIsWeb) {
    // Register the background isolate with the root isolate.
    // comiler still unhappy that this member doenst exist, but it should simply skip this block 
    BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(input.rootIsolateToken);
}
```

i'm looking for a solution similar to C's `#if`, `#endif`

is this a flutter bug or am i supposed to wrap the BackGroundIsolateBinaryMessenger in my own lib like described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61921960/15289577)?

or can i somehow mark the if statement as const s.t. it gets evaluated at compile time?

Comment: you check with Platform instead of kIsWeb